# How to show error message of specific fields which are coming from server side in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on Spring Boot and Angular 7 example. In this example, for server side validations, I am getting all validation errors in `fieldErrors` object.

```
error.error.fieldErrors

0:
code: "NotBlank"
field: "student]Desc"
message: "Student Description is mandatory"
resource: "studentDto"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

0:
code: "NotBlank"
field: "studentEmail"
message: "Student Email is mandatory"
resource: "studentDto"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have developed below method, but not sure to show specific error message of each individual field

```
handleError(error: any) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      this.errorProgramName = error.error.message;

      if (error.error.fieldErrors) {
        const fieldErrors = error.error.fieldErrors;
        console.log(fieldErrors[].field);
        console.log(error.error.fieldErrors.message);
        this.errorProgramDesc = error.error.fieldErrors.field;
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="input">
    <label class="">
        Description
    </label>
    <div class="input-container">
        <textarea class="input-box" aria-required="true" rows="5" [(ngModel)]="student.studentDesc"
            name="programDesc"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="error required" aria-label="Please select this field">
        {{errorStudentName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you show your fields?

Comment: @paa You can inspect the control's state by exporting `ngModel` to `trv`

Comment: @Webruster - Sorry I am not clear on this. I am newbie

Comment: @PAA your `ngModel` (i.e. `student`) will have properties like angular form validation parameters like `ngpristine, `valid` ,`invalid`,`touched` ,`ngdirty` . so based on specific errors you can enable specific appropriate error messages

Comment: Oh Ok, Could you please share link to sample code ?

Comment: @PAA sorry, i didn't know you replied , you having issue or it cleared?